# What is exact location of mediapipe's pose keypoints

Tags: mediapipe

I cannot find information about exact location of mediapipe's keypoints location only less informative e.g. left hip but for me it's crucial to know if left hip mean left hip joint or or pelvis. I've read research papers, blog, etc and cannot find anything :(